# What index we should create for group by() queries in janus?

Tags: java, indexing, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have a sample use case in janus where student and skills are my nodes.
For a given student, I need to find similar student based on most skill overlap.
I have written the following gremlin query,

```java
  g.V().
  has('Student', 'id', '1234').as('can').
  out('HAS_SKILL').
  inE('HAS_SKILL').
  aggregate('users').
  group().by(outV().values('name').as('sks')).
  unfold().
  project('total_count', 'similarUser', 'count', 'skills').
    by(select('users').unfold().outV().dedup().count()).
    by(select(keys)).
    by(select(values).count(local)).
    by(select(values).unfold().inV().values('skillName').fold()).
  order().by('count', desc).
  limit(10)
```

I have a composite index  on id.My question is, do we need index on 'name' field too , because I am using group by? If yes, what type of index I should create on 'name' (composite/mixed)?I tried with composite but my query is taking very much time

Answer (score 2):

JanusGraph will give you a warning or an error (depending if full graph scans are enabled) if a query is not being fully backed by the index that you have created. Further, adding a `.profile()` to your query will show you the current index usage. If you are seeing the warning/error then you need to take further index action.

Here is an example using the `inmemory` backend, with the air-routes data set loaded.

```
gremlin> graph=JanusGraphFactory.open('inmemory')
==>standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]]

gremlin> g=graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]

gremlin> g.io('air-routes-latest.xml').read()
```

If we try to run a query now, we get the index warning

```
gremlin> g.V().has('code',within('AUS','SFO','DFW')).group().by('code')
10:10:40 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [((code = AUS OR code = SFO OR code = DFW))]. For better performance, use indexes

==>[DFW:[v[12512]],SFO:[v[20568]],AUS:[v[4096]]]
```

So now let's create an index

```
gremlin> graph.tx().rollback()
==>null

gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()

==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@8e25d3f

gremlin> idx = mgmt.buildIndex('airportIndex',Vertex.class)

==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem$IndexBuilder@388c519

gremlin> iata = mgmt.getPropertyKey('code')
==>code

gremlin> idx.addKey(iata).buildCompositeIndex()
==>airportIndex

gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==null

gremlin> mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'airportIndex').
......1>      status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call()

==>GraphIndexStatusReport[success=true, indexName='airportIndex', targetStatus=[REGISTERED], notConverged={}, converged={code=REGISTERED}, elapsed=PT6.016S]
```

Now we need to re-index

```
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@6637a365

gremlin> mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("airportIndex"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
==>org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.scan.StandardScanMetrics@6ee88e21

gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
```

The `profile()` will now show us if the index was used

```
gremlin> g.V().has('code','SFO').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[code.eq(SFO)])                                      1           1           0.714   100.00
  constructGraphCentricQuery                                                                   0.173
  GraphCentricQuery                                                                            0.307
    \_condition=(code = SFO)
    \_orders=[]
    \_isFitted=true
    \_isOrdered=true
    \_query=multiKSQ[1]
    \_index=airportIndex
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.714        -
```

Lastly we can try to again group using the `code` property, and we get no warnings this time as the query is backed by the index.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('code',within('AUS','SFO','DFW')).group().by('code')
==>[DFW:[v[4240]],SFO:[v[20584]],AUS:[v[8312]]]
```

The same index will also work if we add a traversal to the `by` modulator. In fact the index is not even needed to resolve `values('code')` as it was already used to find the starting point, and after the `out` a set of additional vertices is already found.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('code','SAF').group().by(out().values('code').fold())
==>[[DFW,LAX,PHX,DEN]:[v[24600]]]
```

So in summary for this type of `group` operation, you should just be able to use the "built-in" JanusGraph composite index and not need to resort to an external (mixed) index, unless you are unable to do exact match type lookups.